# OPENGL C++ tiles rendered with small gaps between them

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have been attempting to recreate my pygame RPG in c++ due to performance problems in pygame. I have started rendering tiles. However when these tiles rendered if you go into full screen, you can see lines between the tiles which I believe to be caused by rounding errors when I calculate the locations of the tiles, or the texture vertices. I made a system to convert integers -1.0f to 1.0f coordinates opengl use which I think is rounding or not doing it correctly, I couldn't figure out what to change to remove the gaps between them.

Here is an image of what I see

https://ibb.co/PDZ5fRT

Here is the code for my tile class

```
class Tile {
public:

//coordinates for placement and texture coordinates
/*
b = bottom
t = top
l = left
r = right5
x,y = x,y lol dumbass
t = texture coordinate
*/
float bl_x, tl_x, tr_x, br_x, bl_y, tl_y, tr_y, br_y;
float t_bl_x, t_bl_y, t_tl_x, t_tl_y, t_tr_x, t_tr_y, t_br_x, t_br_y;

Tile(int x, int y, int width, int height, std::vector<float>* vertices, std::vector<unsigned int>* indices) {
    
    unsigned int tex_x = 0.0f;
    unsigned int tex_y = 2.0f * 32.0f;
    int SCR_WIDTH = 640;
    int SCR_HEIGHT = 360;
    //convert x,y coords to open gl coords (between -1 and 1) (prop means proportion of screen)
    float x_prop = float(float(x) / float(SCR_WIDTH)) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    float y_prop = float(float(y) / float(SCR_HEIGHT)) * 2 - 1;
    float width_prop = float(float(x + width) / float(SCR_WIDTH)) * 2.0f - 1.0f;
    float height_prop = float(float(y + height) / float(SCR_HEIGHT)) * 2 - 1;

    //convert texture x,y coords open gl coords (BETWEEN 0 and 1) (prop means proportion of screen)
    
    float tex_x_prop = float(float(tex_x) / 641.0f);
    float tex_y_prop = float(float(tex_y) / 288.0f);
    float tex_width_prop = float(float(tex_x + width) / 641.0f);
    float tex_height_prop = float(float(tex_y + height) / 288.0f);
    
    tl_x = x_prop;
    tl_y = y_prop;
    bl_x = x_prop;
    bl_y = height_prop;
    br_x = width_prop;
    br_y = height_prop;
    tr_x = width_prop;
    tr_y = y_prop;


    //texture coordinates
    t_bl_x = tex_x_prop;
    t_bl_y = tex_y_prop;
    t_tl_x = tex_x_prop;
    t_tl_y = tex_height_prop;
    t_tr_x = tex_width_prop;
    t_tr_y = tex_height_prop;
    t_br_x = tex_width_prop;
    t_br_y = tex_y_prop;

    // --- push back coordinates to the vertex buffer----
        //bottom left coords
    vertices->push_back(bl_x);
    vertices->push_back(bl_y);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    //bottom left color
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);

    //bottom left texture coords
    vertices->push_back(t_bl_x);
    vertices->push_back(t_bl_y);

    //top left coords
    vertices->push_back(tl_x);
    vertices->push_back(tl_y);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);

    //top left color
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);

    //top left texture coords
    vertices->push_back(t_tl_x);
    vertices->push_back(t_tl_y);

    //top right coords
    vertices->push_back(tr_x);
    vertices->push_back(tr_y);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    //top right color
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);

    //top right texture coords
    vertices->push_back(t_tr_x);
    vertices->push_back(t_tr_y);

    //bottom right coords
    vertices->push_back(br_x);
    vertices->push_back(br_y);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    //bottom right color
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    vertices->push_back(0.0f);
    //bottom right texture coords
    vertices->push_back(t_br_x);
    vertices->push_back(t_br_y);

    // --- push back indices ---
    unsigned int p = indices->size() / 6 * 4;
    indices->push_back(0 + p);
    indices->push_back(1 + p);
    indices->push_back(3 + p);
    indices->push_back(1 + p);
    indices->push_back(2 + p);
    indices->push_back(3 + p);
}

};
```

Comment: Looks like bleeding artifacts to me.
Try to render with point filtering

Comment: ah yes thank you I didn't even think of that!

Comment: @William_Redding: You can also add padding to the textures in your atlas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by changing from GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST when rendering :) Thank you Raildex

Answer (score 0):

Once I found me in the same situation (thin lines between some tiles), I decided to jump from texture-per-tile approach to "single texture, logical tiles" one. So, all tiles should be rendered into one big texture according to their logical position on the screen. Then, the computed big texture to be passed to OpenGL renderer.